# What's the tl;dr investing rules for married Canadian citizens when one partner happens to have US citizenship?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, canada, citizenship

Canadians with US citizenship have several things to consider regarding investments:

1. Canada's Tax-Free Savings Account (TFSA) is not considered tax free by IRS, and filing taxes may significantly harm the gain.
2. [PFIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_foreign_investment_company) taxation applies for purchasing non-US (i.e. Canadian) products (stocks, mutual funds, etc.).

What is the generic "best case" scenario for married Canadians, when one partner happens to be a US citizen, for minimizing taxation in this case?

In particular:

1. Shared bank account - yes or no?
2. US citizen should contribute only to RRSP - yes or no?
3. Use US citizen's TFSA only for USD investments - yes or no?
4. Open bank account in the US - yes or no?

(I'm asking for the right thing to do - not for evading.)

Comment: Is the Canadian spouse subject to the US laws?

Comment: @littleadv no (not yet)

Comment: This is similar to another question, https://money.stackexchange.com/q/43943/7867 , and the answers to that question may be helpful here.